# Where to store key during Firebase custom login

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am coupling Node.JS with Firebase and planning to use LinkedIn to log users in.

**On the backend I have:**

```
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
var mySecret = 'XXXXX'


module.exports = function (app, passport) {

    app.get('/fire', function (req, res) {
        var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator(mySecret);
        var token = tokenGenerator.createToken({                                            
            "app_user_id": 123X, "isModerator": true
        });

    res.render('firebase-index.ejs', {token: token, kale: 'mazing'}); })
};
```

**On the template firebase-index.ejs:**

Here I'm not sure how to store the token for use during auth. I cant seem to directly use it unless I insert it into a DOM element like this

```
<span id="token"><%= token %><span>
```

Then I can access it with 'token.textContent' below

```
dataRef.auth(token.textContent, function(error) {
    if(error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
    } else {
        console.log("Login Succeeded!");
        console.log(token.textContent);
    }
});
```

Is this the safe/ preferred way to do this? Also, after I log in, How do I access the auth variable? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time in modern apps, you'd make a request to your server API for the auth token, rather than sending the auth token as part of the HTML body. This is done by making an HTTP call to your back end, which would return a JSON object (i.e. an asynchronous request).

Server code (assuming express):

```
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator(process.env.FIREBASE_SECRET);

app.get('/authToken', function(req, res){
   var token = tokenGenerator.createToken({some: "arbitrary", data: "here"});
   res.json(token);
});
```

Client code (assuming jQuery):

```
$.getJSON( "https://SERVER/authToken", function( token ) {
   console.log(token);
});
```

If you're stuck with returning it as part of the view/html data, you could inject it directly into a JavaScript variable (since you are generating it and know it does not contain any malicious code).

Here I'll just use window (i.e. a global) but you'd prefer to have some scoped object (e.g. myApp.config.authToken) you could attach it into instead.

```
<script>window.authToken = '<%= token %>';<script>
```

Comment: Just curious, is there any malicious activity that users pursue with the token?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Nor is security in the scope of answering this straightforward question about tokens. If you want to generate you own tokens it's your job to decide how users authenticated and how security is enforced. Otherwise just use FirebaseSimpleLogin.

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe someone could use the token to assign custom info to the auth variable can pretend to be other users.

Comment: No. To create a token, you need to know the secret for the account. So it's not possible to modify the tokens as a user.